# How to add class to first child with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a class an element on a container with a certain index?

I'm trying this right now which should affect the first element (doesn't work anyway)

```
$('#resultsBox li:first-child').addClass('aaaa');
```

But I want to be able to change class of any element in it's container having the index.

EG if I want to modify element with index = 2.

```
<div id="resultsBox">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Should become:

```
<div id="resultsBox">
<ul>
<li></li> // Index 0
<li></li> // Index 1
<li class="selected"></li> // Index 2
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [**:first**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$('#resultsBox li:first').addClass('aaaa');
```

and for the third element selection, you can use [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:
[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MXLH8/4/)

```
$('ul li').each(function(i) {
    if ( i === 2 ) {
       $(this).addClass('aaaa');
    }
});
```

or you can do this with **[eq](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method like Jamiec & MrThys mentioned: but each method will be much usefull when things getting complicated.

```
$('#resultsBox li').eq(2).addClass('aaaa');
```

Answer (score 7):

The cleanest way of achieving this would be:

```
$('#resultsBox li').eq(2).addClass('selected');
```

Documentation on the .eq method can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 2):

Use the :first selector, or the :nth-child selector. I mention the :nth-child selector simply in case you want to add classes to anything other than the first. You can also use :nth-child in plain CSS without javascript if you want

```
$("#resultBox li:nth-child(1)").addClass('aaa');
```

Answer (score 1):

For select ul

```
$("#resultsBox ul").first().addClass( "aaaa" );
```

For select first li

```
$("#resultsBox ul li").first().addClass( "aaaa" );
```

Answer (score 0):

[`eq selector`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('#resultsBox li:eq(2)').addClass('aaaa');
```

or [`eq function`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('#resultsBox li').eq(2).addClass('aaaa');
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to use the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), since the selector is a jQuery extension and not part of CSS.