# How can we add class to the first div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML like

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

and I want to add a class to all the first div having class sub and parent main. ie; I wanted HTML like

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub newclass"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="sub newclass"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

How can I implement this using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add class to first child with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859509/how-to-add-class-to-first-child-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code

► **Method 1**

```
$('.main').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub').first().addClass('newclass');
});
```

**Working  Demo**

```js
$('.main').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub').first().addClass('newclass');
});
```

```css
.newclass{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
 </div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
 </div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
 </div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
 </div><div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
 </div>
```

► **Method 2**

```
$('.main').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub').eq(0).addClass('newclass');
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$('.main').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub').eq(0).addClass('newclass');
});
```

```css
.newclass{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
</div>
```

► **Method 3**

```
$('.main').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub:eq(0)').addClass('newclass');
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$('.main').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub:eq(0)').addClass('newclass');
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div>
</div>
```

**References**

► [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

► [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

► [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: Thankx, Rino. I got it , but I want to add the new class for all the first div having the parent class main. (Question Edited)

Comment: Always glad to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
$('.main div:first-child').addClass('newClass');
```

I have a working demo here JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/8xeaybhL/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/8xeaybhL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use selector to  `:first`

```
$('.main .sub:first').addClass('newclass');
```

Comment: Thankx, Lalji. I got it , but I want to add the new class for all the first div having the parent class main.(Question edited)