# Add class to child <li> under <ul> when div is clicked

Tags: jquery

the un-ordered lists on the page has an id but the child li elements has no class. i'm trying assign a class to all of the first level li elements when the parent div "top_nav" is clicked

i tried the below jquery script

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div#top_nav ul li', function {
  $(this).child().addclass('new-class')
});
```

```html
<div id="top-nav">
  <a id="nav-icon">show nav</a>
  <ul id="root-nav">
    <li class="active">First Menu Item </li>
    <li>First Menu Item </li>
    <li>First Menu Item </li>
    <li>First Menu Item </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

after running the code , the class is not getting added when the div is clicked. can i have a second set of eyes just in case i'm missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add class to first child with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859509/how-to-add-class-to-first-child-with-jquery)

Comment: Also, you're attaching the event listener to the `<li>` elements, not the `<div>`, so the `$(this)` is referring to the `<li>` which has no children.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to add a class to all the LI children, you can simply add a class to their common parent and handle the rest using CSS `.new-class > * {`

Comment: You also have a syntax error: `function {` should be `function() {`.

Comment: Another typo: `div#top_nav` should be `div#top-nav`. And there's no `.child()` method in jQuery, it's call `.children()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of typos in your code. You're missing the `()` after `function`. `.child()` should be `.children()` and `.addclass()` should be `.addClass()`. `#top_nav` should be `#top-nav`.

You have the event handler on the wrong element. If you want to click on the `top-nav` element, it should be delegated to `div#top-nav`, not `div#top-nav ul li`. The `li` elements aren't direct children of `top-nav`, so you need to use `.find()` rather than `.children()`.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div#top-nav', function() {
  $(this).find('> ul > li').addClass('new-class')
});
```

```css
.new-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-nav">
  <a id="nav-icon">show nav</a>
  <ul id="root-nav">
    <li class="active">First Menu Item </li>
    <li>First Menu Item </li>
    <li>First Menu Item </li>
    <li>First Menu Item </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```